# Iterating through a golang map

Tags: dictionary, go, loops

I have a map of type: `map[string]interface{}`

And finally, I get to create something like (after deserializing from a yml file using goyaml)

```
mymap = map[foo:map[first: 1] boo: map[second: 2]]
```

How can I iterate through this map? I tried the following:

```
for k, v := range mymap{
...
}
```

But I get an error:

```
cannot range over mymap
typechecking loop involving for loop
```

Please help.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a test case? It's hard to diagnose the problem from what you've posted, since there's nothing inherent to what you've posted that could cause a type checking loop. In particular, I'm having trouble figuring out how you'd get a type checking loop in a function body.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    type Map1 map[string]interface{}
    type Map2 map[string]int
    m := Map1{"foo": Map2{"first": 1}, "boo": Map2{"second": 2}}
    //m = map[foo:map[first: 1] boo: map[second: 2]]
    fmt.Println("m:", m)
    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Println("k:", k, "v:", v)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
m: map[boo:map[second:2] foo:map[first:1]]
k: boo v: map[second:2]
k: foo v: map[first:1]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could just write it out in multiline like this,

```
$ cat dict.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        items := map[string]interface{}{
                "foo": map[string]int{
                        "strength": 10,
                        "age": 2000,
                },
                "bar": map[string]int{
                        "strength": 20,
                        "age": 1000,
                },
        }
        for key, value := range items {
                fmt.Println("[", key, "] has items:")
                for k,v := range value.(map[string]int) {
                        fmt.Println("\t-->", k, ":", v)
                }

        }
}
```

And the output:

```
$ go run dict.go
[ foo ] has items:
        --> strength : 10
        --> age : 2000
[ bar ] has items:
        --> strength : 20
        --> age : 1000
```

Comment: thank you. what would call the portion of the code `value.(map[string]int)`? is that called "coercing `value` to a new type" in Go? (new to Go)

Comment: @123 I think, type assertion https://go.dev/tour/methods/15

Answer (score 3):

You can make it by one line:

```
mymap := map[string]interface{}{"foo": map[string]interface{}{"first": 1}, "boo": map[string]interface{}{"second": 2}}
for k, v := range mymap {
    fmt.Println("k:", k, "v:", v)
}
```

Output is:

```
k: foo v: map[first:1]
k: boo v: map[second:2]
```

Comment: Go Proverb: Don't be clever, be explicit. One-liners are not the goal in Go.